# Unable to apply text color to table row with bootstrap

Tags: html-table, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5.3. I want to apply a text color across an entire table row.

```
<tr class="fw-bold text-primary">
   <td>Java</td>
   <td>Php</td>
   <td>Javascript</td>
   <td>Go</td>
</tr>
```

`
in the above example code. fw-bold is applied, The entire text in the row is made bold. But the color of the texts in the row don't change. Pls note that I don't want to change the background color, its the text color I want to change. Don't want to have to do it by table data (td)

I have tried to table-primary but it applies color to the background

Answer (score 1):

**How to make Bootstrap text colors work with table rows**

*...and without unintended side effects*

**Problem**

Applying a Bootstrap text color to a table row has no effect on table cell text.

There are Bootstrap classes to change [table theme colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/tables/#variants), but the text is always light or dark. Applying a color to a row does not work as it is overridden by the theme color.

```
<!-- does not work -->
<tr class="text-primary"><td>Hello World</td></tr>
```

To change the color of a row you would need to set the text color on each table cell within the row:

```
<!-- works -->
<tr><td class="text-primary">Hello World</td></tr>
```

**Solution**

A bit of custom css is required to make Bootstrap text colors work with table rows.

```
tr.text-primary td,
tr.text-primary th {
  color: inherit;
}
```

This causes the cells to inherit the color applied to the row. To avoid unwanted side effects, the solution is narrowly scoped and does not use `!important`. Individual cells can still be styled differently from the row.

**Demo Snippet**

```css
tr.text-primary td,
tr.text-primary th {
  color: inherit;
}

tr.text-danger th,
tr.text-danger td {
  color: inherit;
}

/* other text colors not shown */
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover fw-bold">
  <tr class="text-primary">
    <td>Java</td>
    <td>Php</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
    <td>Go</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-danger">
    <td>Java</td>
    <td>Php</td>
    <td>Javascript</td>
    <td>Go</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-primary">
    <td>Java</td>
    <td class="text-success">Php</td>
    <td class="text-danger">Javascript</td>
    <td class="text-warning">Go</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you can unset specific table variables overriding utility classes, for example, color, by adding it after Bootstrap stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
/* reset stuff */
.table {
  --bs-table-color: initial;
}
</style>
```

demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
  /* reset stuff */
  
  .table {
    --bs-table-color: initial;
  }
</style>


<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="fw-bold text-primary">
      <td>Java</td>
      <td>Php</td>
      <td>Javascript</td>
      <td>Go</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

related issue on github at the moment:

> [v5.3.0: Table rows can no longer be colored with text-bg-* #38779](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/38779)

Comment: Oh yeah. Saw the GitHub issue but I couldn't see help from there. I can try this... Thanks alot